# ASP vs Inc behavior difference with html.encode

Tags: asp-classic, include, html.encode

For my current project i work with include files (.inc) inside visual studio.

What i did is changed some inc files to asp.

But when i consult my page i have a strange behavior with special characters.

Examples
AndrÃ© for André

Privï¿½ for privé

When i use html.encode i do not get any good result.

In versioncontrol i noticed the only thing that's changed are the extentions for the include files.

Is this normal behavior ?

What did i mis or do wrong ?

Comment: just guessing... try changing encoding in your text editor and try to save files again.

Comment: If you open your files in Notepad and select Save As from the File dropdown, then select UTF-8 in the encoding dropdown rather than ANSI, this might solve your problem.  I'm not sure how to perform this operation within VS itself, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cuase of my problem.

In visual studio each file i create is in UTF-8 encoding.

What i need to do is change the encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In vs-2019, you can save a file with encoding:

> 1. From the File menu, choose Save File As, and then click the drop-down button next to the Save button.
> 2. The Advanced Save Options dialog box is displayed.
> 3. Under Encoding, select the encoding to use for the file.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2019#to-save-a-file-with-encoding][1]